# How are these keyboard buttons called?

Tags: keyboard

I bought a new keyboard and it has weird type of keys: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxMNG.jpg
There are like 2 layers of it. Do those kind of keys have a specific name? I'm not sure if it is because I had my old keyboard for around 4 years but I think those buttons are very uncomfortable.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any special name https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_key#/media/File:Qwerty.svg even if the wikipedia seem to include them like cursor keys https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_keyboard#Cursor_keys

Comment: I... don't get it, what's the problem here? You're surprised by the existence of the navigation keys (insert, delete etc) or are your keys mechanically/structurally strange?

Comment: mechanically/structurally strange